# While Loop Store In Array php

Tags: php

I am extremely new at php and I was wondering if someone could help me

Hi folks
i want to store while loop in array how it is possible?

e.g
Code (text):

```
<?php
$i=1;
while($i<=5)
  {
  echo $i . "<br>";
  $i++;
  }
?>
```

my requirements
$store_array=[1,2,3,4,5];

Comment: $store_array = range(1,5); OR $i=1; $store_array = array();
while($i<=5)
  {
  $store_array[] = $i;
  $i++;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Use [`range()`](http://php.net/range):

```
$store_array = range( 1, 5);
```

Done!

If you really want to use a `while` loop, the syntax would be:

```
$i = 1; 
$store_array = array();
while( $i <= 5)
{
     $store_array[] = $i;
     $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$i=1;
$store_array= array();
while($i<=5)
  {
  echo $i . "<br>";
  array_push($store_array,$i);
  $i++;
  }
 print_r($store_array);
?>
```